# Trivial HAProxy UrlRewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, haproxy

I would like all traffic to an arbitrary domain, let's call it www.example.com, to be url-rewritten to www.google.com so that when I hit http://www.example.com/search?q=haproxy doesn't result in a 404.  Is this even possible?

Here is my .cfg file's content:

```
global

defaults
        mode http
        timeout connect 5000ms
        timeout client 5000ms
        timeout server 5000ms

frontend http-in
        bind *:80
        default_backend my_backend
        reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /\d+/(.+)/?     \1\ /\2

backend my_backend
        server forwardsvr www.google.com:80 check
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Sending traffic to Google like this seems like it would be a violation of their acceptable use policy.  It is possible, if your back-end server returns a 404 to rewrite that response into a browser redirect to somewhere else... like a specific landing page... but it's really not clear what you are actually trying to accomplish.  Can you describe the issue in more detail,  please?

Comment: I'd like a domain overlay/mask such that when I hit domain1.com that it should be forwarded to domain2.com; headers, verbs and all.  In addition it should be totally transparent, i.e. no redirects to new domains, rather the original domain should still be domain1.com in the client browser.  I used google search as a proof of concept.  Incidentally the 404 is coming from google so it would seem it's "kinda" working :)